# How to disable the possibility to set Properties for Controls?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my application I want to prevent other programmers to set properties to my Usercontrols that maybe cause some troubles.

A simple example is that I don't want to allow that someone set `UseLayoutRounding` to true.

```
<Button UseLayoutRounding="True"/>
```

I want to disable that `Intelisense` shows me `UseLayoutRounding`.

Answer (score 1):

You may override `OnPropertyChanged` method and throw exceptions when someone tries to change it:

```
protected override void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Property == UseLayoutRoundingProperty && (bool)e.NewValue)
    {
        throw new PropertyIsImmutableException("UseLayoutRounding");
    }
    //....
    base.OnPropertyChanged(e);
}
```

Or you may use `new` keyword:

```
public new bool UseLayoutRounding
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(UseLayoutRoundingProperty); }
}
```

However, using second aproach without first remains posibility to change value like this:

```
yourSuperControl.SetValue(SuperControlType.UseLayoutRoundingProperty, true);
```

Comment: Thats funtional ok but its not the solution for "Hidden Propertys"

Comment: Why? The setter is disabled and does not shown with IntelliSence when you hide old property with `new` keyword. As far as I know hiding property at all is impossible, this is the best solution